# My ASA has decided to stop sending NetFlow traffic. Is there a way to fix this short of restarting?

Tags: cisco-asa, netflow

I have been running NetFlow successfully on all of my ASAs for the past few months.  Recently, one of my ASA failover pairs has decided to stop sending netflow packets.  Is there a command to restart the subsystem that handles netflow, or any other fix I'm overlooking?  I'd like to see if there are easier options before I move into `reload-standby;reload` situations or even cold cycling the pair.

Relevant config:

```
flow-export destination NYHQ-SERVERS 1.2.3.4 12346
flow-export template timeout-rate 1

policy-map global_policy
 class class-default
  set connection decrement-ttl
  user-statistics accounting
  flow-export event-type all destination 1.2.3.4
!

ASA# sh flow counter
destination: NYHQ-SERVERS 1.2.3.4 12346
  Statistics:
    packets sent                                         45442077
  Errors:
    block allocation failure                                    0
    invalid interface                                           0
    template send failure                                       0
    no route to collector                                       0
    source port allocation failure                              0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason and it was a stupid mistake.  For some reason the global policy was not enabled globally.  By executing `service-policy global_policy global` I got netflow talking once again.